Does python 3.12 allows to append items from the list to tuple, I am trying this but getting error TYPEERROR: 'tuple' object is not callable
Please find the below code, once I execute this code I am getting 'tuple' object is not callable error please give the solution, thanks in advance.

`mytuple = ("apple", "banana", "cherry")
names = list (mytuple)
names.append("orange")
mytuple = tuple (names)

print(mytuple)`


Here I tried to add item("orange") to a tuple, we can't directly add or change items in the tuple because tuples are immutable, so that what I did is I converted the tuple to a list with new name called names then I was added with "orange" using append function and then I was changed that list(names) to tuple and print the mytuple.
then finally I am getting error.

Make sure that you have not inadvertently overwritten the built-in tuple function. Here is the corrected version of your code:
mytuple = ("apple", "banana", "cherry")



# Convert tuple to list
names = list(mytuple)

# Append "orange" to the list
names.append("orange")

# Convert list back to tuple
mytuple = tuple(names)

# Print the updated tuple
print(mytuple)

When executed, this will correctly output:
('apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'orange')


It's great for getting the solution immediately.
